# "Unable to open image" error when using ImageMagick's Filename References

Tags: reference, imagemagick, filenames

I'm using ImageMagick to do some image processing from the commandline, and would like to operate on a list of files as specified in foo.txt. From the instructions here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php I see that I can use Filename References from a file prefixed with @. When I run something like:

> montage @foo.txt output.jpg

everything works as expected, as long as foo.txt is in the current directory. However, when I try to access bar.txt in a different directory by running:

> montage /some_directory/@bar.txt
>   output2.jpg

I get:

> montage: unable to open image
>   /some_directory/@bar.txt: No such file
>   or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2480.

I believe the issue is my syntax, but I'm not sure what to change it to. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Quite an old entry but it seems relatively obvious that you need to put the @ before the full path:

```
montage @/some_directory/bar.txt output2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

As of ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2014-02-10, paths are not supported with @ syntax.  The @ file must be in the current directory and identified by name only.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried directing IM to pull the list of files from a file, but I do specify multiple files on the command line like this:

```
gm -sOutputFile=dest.ext -f file1.ppm file2.ppm file3.ppm
```

Can you pull the contents of that file into a variable, and then let the shell expand that variable?

Comment: I have a a very large number of files in different directories (1K+) I'm merging together, so I'd prefer not to I think listing them in file and pointing to that file seems like the most reasonable thing to do.